# fullcalendar is shifting dates from the database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using arshaw's fullcalendar for Asp.net webforms.  When I add a calendar event, it shows it at the proper time, and enters the time correctly in the database.

However, when you go back to the calendar to view the event, it shifts the time.  I assumed it was because of the timezone.  My server is in CST and I'm on EST, so it's shifting the time by an hour.

I've looked around and tried to add the ignoreTimeZone setting, but it's not changing anything.  I also used JSON to pass the user's timezone from their browser to offset the time.  However that's not reliable.

How can I make the fullcalendar simply load the dates by what they are in the database instead of shifting them?

Answer (score 0):

arshaw has demonstrated simply setting timezone: to timezone string can take care of everything but i could not get it to work when using events: function form, where i get timestamps.

If the database returns epoch timestamps, in case you are using events: as function in the response handler you can adjust the start and end of each event you create by the devices local timezone and the users timezone whose calendar you are viewing.

other wise there is a callback function eventRender: to adjust the compensation for the two kinds of timezone that comes in to play.